# What is the footprint of a greenlet in gevent?

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets

I am trying to create this service which makes async http calls. For this I am using gevent with a set of greenlets defined in a pool.

The users will make a request to this service which will be put in a queue. Now the greenlets in the pool will read from the queue, make corresponding http calls to fetch data related to the request. I am wondering how many greenlets should I spawn. I am not sure whats the cost of each greenlet?

How do I define the number of greenlets?

Comment: The footprint of a greenlet is small compared toba thread. How many you should spawn is a question of your code, your latencies and your calling profile.

Comment: @KlausD. Could you please quantify small? Lets say they just make http calls to www.google.com in each greenlet. Is 200 a decent number? I mean lets say the latency, other factors are fine. I just want to make sure that if I spawn 200 greenlets that itself won't cause much issue.

Comment: Well, you will have to find the best value yourself by testing. Remember that there is not just the happy path and failures have a large impact on the performance.